# Eclipse CDT using CygwinGCC toolchain cannot debug if app links with dll?

Tags: c, dll, eclipse-cdt

Why wouldn't my Eclipse CDT find an `x.dll` where I specified via
`C C++ General/Paths and Symbols/Libraries` (this is the lib name without extension `x`)
`C C++ General/Paths and Symbols/Library Paths` (this is full path to dll)?

I'm on Windows 8.1, using CygwinGCC toolchain, debugging via gdb.

The `app.exe` is built OK, Eclipse project seems to see the dll at this point (for example, if I misspell the dll name, it complains and fails to build). However, when I try to debug the app, I get an ugly unhandled exception message right at startup.

When I manualy copy the needed `x.dll` to sit in the same directory as `app.exe`, then I can debug with no problems.

Comment: real simple.  GCC and cygwin are for unix libraries NOT .dll libraries

Comment: @user3629249 Could you elaborate?

Comment: no need to elaborate.  Different OSs use different library formats.

Comment: You said "`C C++ General/Paths and Symbols/Library Paths` (this is full path to dll)". Did you mean the full path to the directory containing the dll? I'm pretty sure that's what `Library Paths` expects, not a path to the dll file itself.